# How to use selenium to interact with javascript web3 page via metamask

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, metamask

I'm trying to use selenium by connecting metamask to a dapp, I am able to set up metamask using the chromium extension, but i'm having difficulty clicking on the connect button via the metamask option below: https://www.premint.xyz/login/?next=/afterlif3-raffle/

So I am able to locate the `connect` button via the following but im not too sure how to choose the metamask option.

```
driver.get(link)
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Connect')
continue_link.click()
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-styled btn-base-1 btn-circle']")
button.click()
```

Basically what I want to do is to try and connect the metamask wallet with this site. I would definitely appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the relative xpath wrong.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Login with MetaMask']")
```

with this it worked for me.